# Implementation of rainbow style for multiple cells in a notebook

Tags: notebooks, cells

We are aware that a user may utilize 'ColorFunction' gradients such as 'Rainbow' for plotting.
How can we implement a gradient style as a rainbow spectrum to multiple cells in which there are multiple lines of commands, as shown in the image below?

[image]

I am aware of one method: using "Background Color" manually for each cell. However, if the number of cells is substantial, this procedure would be lengthy. How can this process be automatically implemented?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is this what you are after?

```
colors = ColorData["Rainbow"] /@ Range[0, 1, .1];

With[{colors = colors, length = Length@colors},
 
 SetOptions[
  EvaluationNotebook[],
  StyleDefinitions -> Notebook[{
     Cell[StyleData[StyleDefinitions -> "Default.nb"]],
     Cell[StyleData["Input"],
      Background -> FEPrivate`Part[
        colors,
        FEPrivate`Mod[FrontEnd`CurrentValue[{"CounterValue", "Input"}], length, 1]
        ]
      ]
     }
    , StyleDefinitions -> "PrivateStylesheetFormatting.nb"
    ]
  ]
 
 
 
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: Wonderfull and excellent!!!!